# How to export C++ function as a dll that throws exception?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-warnings, dllexport

When I try to export the following function as a dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void some_func()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("test throwing exception");
}
```

Visual C++ 2008 gives me the following warning:

```
1>.\SampleTrainer.cpp(11) : warning C4297: 'some_func' : function assumed not to throw an exception but does
1>        The function is extern "C" and /EHc was specified
```

I need to extern "C" because I use Qt QLibrary to load the dll and resolve the function name. Without extern "C" it can't find the some_func() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are determined to do what the compiler is warning you about, why not just suppress the warning?

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4247)
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. However, is there any other way around this? I actually just want to export a C++ function.

Comment: Then don't use extern "C", instead then use a .def file to force the exported name to be the undecorated name (or whatever you want).

Comment: alternatively, you can try and figure out how to get QT to load the C++ decorated name.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know `/EHs` must be used in case you need a "C" function that can throw. See this: [/EH (Exception Handling Model)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You need to set this in your VisualStudio Project.

On the contrary `/EHc` tells the compiler to assume that extern C functions never throw a C++ exception. And your compiler complains you that your `void some_func()` do throw.